# RegEx in Powershell to replace space in XML element name with underscore

Tags: regex, powershell

I have an XML document with element names with a space or multiple spaces in it (which is not allowed in XML) and I am looking for a regex to replace the space with an _ and after modifications replace the _ with a space again. The regex can be applied to a string.

Simplified Sample XML where I want to replace `<User Blob> to <User_Blob>` but I don't want to replace eg My Space to My_Space. So the RegEx needs to match a < followed by one or more words with a space in it, followed by > I think.

```
<User Data Blob> 
    <Item> 
        <Key>SomeKey</Key> 
        <Value>false</Value> 
    </Item> 
    <Item> 
        <Key>AnotherKey</Key> 
        <Value></Value> 
    </Item> 
</User Data Blob>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-Content .\file.xml | Foreach-Object {
    [regex]::replace($_,'<([^>]+)>',{$args[0] -replace ' ','_'})
}
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly with both Single Space but also for elements with multiple spaces eg <My Element Name>.

Comment: That was my goal, any space in the element name should be replaced.

Comment: You should open a new thread. Changing the requirements after answers has been posted makes all answers irrelevant.

Comment: Passing scriptblocks as delegates is awesome. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

From Space to Underscore:

```
(gc .\FileWithSpace.xml)| % { $_ -replace "<(/?)(\w+) (\w+)>", '<$1$2_$3>'}
```

From Underscore to Space:

```
(gc .\FileWithUnderscore.xml)| % { $_ -replace "<(/?)(\w+)_(\w+)>", '<$1$2 $3>'}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for one space but not for multiple eg <An Element Name>

Comment: Improve your requeriments, say exactly what you need, and I'm going to fix the answer

Comment: @voodoosmr: great, I edited the question to make clear that I meant one or more spaces in the element name.

Comment: I check the solution of @ShayLevy, and is perfect. Should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex flavor used supports lookahead you could do things like:

```
 (?=[<>]*>)
```

(Notice the space in front.) Replace with `_`.

To reverse do:

```
_(?=[<>]*>)
```

Replaced with a space.

Comment: afaik PowerShell/.net regex supports lookaheads but this work: [regex]::Replace("<User Blob>", ' ?=([<>]*>)', '_')

Comment: @Remko, `?=` before the `(` for a lookahead? Seems wrong to me. No regex flavor I know of has such syntax, and I doubt MS would introduce it.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, works should be does not work :-( but I am unsure how to use the regex from your sample in Powershell...

Comment: @Remko, use it like any other regex, and copy and paste it so you get it right. Also, I don't know powershell, but I guess I could read the manual for you. (-;

Comment: Here is how you could do it in Perl if you have that: `perl -p -e "s/ (?=[<>]*>)/_/g" special.xml`